# How will language work without sounds or body language?

Tags: aliens, communication, language, internet

I'm picturing a specie of intelligent aliens evolving on a familiar yet different Earth-like environment, these beings are capable of empathy and shares many similar psychological traits with us human. However, as they lack bones or faces they are incapable of typical human communication. They  communicate with one another by merging with each other (they are slime like creature) such as the collective hive mind.

**Question**

Can they develop language(s) and dialect(s)?

**Note**

They are amorphous but not ethereal.

They can't see but hear. (vibration)

They merge their body and mind to communicate.

They will de-fusion/split apart to end commhnication.

They reproduce asexually through cell division.

They can extend part of their body to form as many as hundred of tentacles  to grip object.

By touching with a single tentacle on each other they can only feel emotion but not thought.

P.S. As this is my first attempt on language comment below if there is any doubt pertaining to my alien species.

Comment: I think you've just described Sergeant Schlock from Schlock Mercenary. http://www.schlockmercenary.com/

Comment: I think you answer your own question: "to communicate with one another they will have to merge with each other." This pretty much rules out an audial form of communication.

Comment: @Frostfyre not in the way like how the ants uses scent to talk, I mean they come up with make up patterns to describe object properties in great details.

Comment: on earth known ways of communicating include color changing, sound, touch, chemical signals including smell, posture/position signals, ect.

Answer (score 2):

A language is a codified representation of a set of ideas that allows one organism to convey information to the information processing center of another organism. Humans use speech, body language and facial expressions to convey meaning and emotion. The animal kingdom is by no means restricted to those communication methods.

[Slime molds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold) secrete a chemical signal to one another to induce individual slime mold cells to form into a multicellular organism. Any number of birds use bright plumage and complex dances to indicate a willingness to mate. Ants use chemical trails to lead nest mates to food sources. The list goes on and on.

But those are mundane. Let's get a bit more exotic!

**Complex Molecular Signals**

If the blobs have the ability to synthesize complex (heavy) molecules then those could be used as a way of communicating. Perhaps titanium represents strength or sulphur an undesirable situation. Each element added to the molecule changes its meaning. There may be problems with sequencing a message although a massively parallel "read" mechanism alleviate any sequencing problems.

**DNA**

Just as DNA conveys information on how to build proteins, it could just as easily encode memories if the encoding were known to both parties. This approach is the closest to how humans use binary data to encode text, pictures and movies. DNA also enjoys an incredibly high storage density.

**Dialects and Foreigners**

With communication methods as expressive as molecular synthesis, local dialects will naturally arise based on nothing other than availability of local elements. One area may have lots of silicon where another area has lots of carbon. Blobs from different areas may still be able to communicate but the heavy emphasis on lithium in a land with little lithium will instantly label the "speaker" as a foreigner.

Answer (score 0):

If they feel emotion by touch, I assume that hormones can cross between bodies.
If they can communicate by merging, then one would think that their brain signals can then cross over. Believe it or not, Some conjoined twins can communicate through thought. It could work like that.

As for what language two entities would use, if their brains could directly transfer signals, but they have no concept of verbal communication... I feel that this is inconceivable. It's like the sound of one hand clapping.

When I think to myself, I think in English because humans evolved to have parts of the brain devoted to vocal communication. For them, this would not be the case. Their brains would evolve to be extra conducive to rational conversing with direct brain signalling. Who knows the language of the brain?